# How can I send a message to a skype group using the Azure Logic App Skype connector?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, skype-for-business

I have created an azure logic app and I want to have it send a message to a skype group on certain conditions. I have added the Skype for Business connector, but I am not sure how to specify the group to send to. Is there a specific link or id I need to put in the *to* field?

[image: Adding Skype for business connector]

Comment: i've tested the TEAMS connector which works pretty well

Comment: Thanks, but we're not using teams. We're using Skype and until yesterday, I didn't know there was a difference between Skype and Skype for Business. I think that this question is actually asking the wrong thing. My understanding of the azure framework is just getting up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Skype for Business Online` is a preview connector,for now It only supported send message to one people.

If you want to send message with it, you could go to Skype , find the people you want to send message, right click it and choose copy then you will get its email, paste it in the **To**  box.

Or you could choose send mails with `Office 365 outlook`, it supports send to multiple people,just add the **;** between Email addresses.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not what we are looking to do. We have a set of existing group chats and we need to send messages to the group. I'm thinking that this skype connector is not what we want. What should I be using instead?